# Who started the Great Fire of Smyrna in 1922?

Tags: turkey, greece, the-balkans

I wish to know if there is historical evidence that definitively identifies who started the fire in Smyrna in 1922, or, whether we *can* conclude given the available evidence, or if it is more complicated than just assigning fault to some side. There is an article in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsibility_for_the_great_fire_of_Smyrna) with accounts that are contradicting one another. I would like to know if there are other pieces of evidence in academia apart from those that are presented in the article and whether this topic is settled among historians.

Comment: Well, evidence points to chaos caused by Turkish looting and murdering any Christian they could find. In such circumstances individual fires could start in various ways.

Comment: This is a highly contentious issue. It is clear from the linked Wikipedia article that there is no agreement among historians on this matter. The article contains links to many relatively recent studies of the matter. Did you read any of these? If so, maybe you can arrive to your own conclusion.

Comment: Just reread the WP article, and I have to disagree with the idea that its completely up in the air. Enough smoke has been thrown up to cloud the issue, yes. However, eyewitness sources seem pretty much unanimous that Turkish soldiers were at the very least feeding the fires and/or impeding firefighting efforts. So while it isn't certain (and nothing in History is really), its pretty easy to see which versions of events are better sourced.